# Display toggled DIVs in multiple DIVs based on Radio selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have multiple DIVs in a form. Each DIV has two radio buttons and two DIVs inside.
First radio button always CHECKED, so one DIV content is to be displayed as the other hides.
When checked the second radio button DIVs display should be toggled.

I tried solution based on https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-show-hide-div-using-radio-button

But I can not able to get desired solution when I use the check boxes in multiple DIVs. Can anyone help me solve this.

```
<form>

<div id="A">
<label><input checked="checked" type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="red">1st radio button[div A]</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="green">2nd radio button[div A]</label>
<div id="1" class="red">Content in Div 1</div>
<div id="2" class="green">Content in Div 2</div>
</div>


<div id="B">
<label><input checked="checked" type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="red2">1st radio button[div B]</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="green2">2nd radio button[div B]</label>
<div id="3" class="red2">Content in Div 3</div>
<div id="4" class="green2">Content in Div 4</div>
</div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
        $(".box").not(targetBox).hide();
        $(targetBox).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What does your HTML actually look like? What about your javascript? Hard to diagnose what we can't see.

Comment: Please provide a code example of what you have tried so others can quickly access it.

Comment: I have added code with two main DIVs with check-boxes and inside DIVs sample.

Comment: You mention check boxes, which are different from radio buttons. Check boxes allow you to have multiple inputs selected whereas radios do not. Do you mean radios or checkboxes?

Comment: @Jack, Sorry for that. I was Confused. I meant radios only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to do it. First, a couple of pointers.

(1) IDs cannot begin with a number, must begin with an alpha

(2) Only one radio button can be selected out of each radio button group *(a group is identified by the `name=xxxxx` attribute)*. So, either have two radio button groups (as in my example), or accept that if Btn3 is selected, Btn1 cannot be.

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    var activeid = $(this).data('id');
    var div2use = $(this).closest('.bobDiv');
    var subdivs = $(this).closest('.bobDiv').find('div.box');
    $.each( subdivs, function(){
        var tst = this.id;
        if ( tst == activeid){
            $(this).addClass('myactive');
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass('myactive');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
form{display:flex;}
#a, #b{flex:1;}
.box{background:pink;border:1px solid yellow;display:none;}
.myactive{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div id="a" class="bobDiv">
    <label><input data-id="a1" checked type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="red">Btn1 [div1]</label>
    <label><input data-id="a2" type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="green">Btn2 [div1]</label>
    <div id="a1" class="red box myactive">1</div>
    <div id="a2" class="green box">2</div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="b" class="bobDiv">
    <label><input data-id="a3" checked type="radio" name="colorRadio2" value="red2">Btn1 [div2]</label>
    <label><input data-id="a4" type="radio" name="colorRadio2" value="green2">Btn2 [div2]</label>
    <div id="a3" class="red2 box myactive">3</div>
    <div id="a4" class="green2 box">4</div>
  </div>

</form>
```